# Problem with spanish package

Tags: babel, spanish

I hope you're doing great. I have the following problem when I try to compile my document, using the spanish babel package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\tikzstyle{startstop}=[rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5cm, draw=black, fill=red!30]

\tikzstyle{io}=[trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=blue!30]

\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
El término agua generalmente se refiere a la sustancia en su estado líquido, aunque la misma puede hallarse en su forma sólida llamada hielo, y en su forma gaseosa denominada vapor. Es una sustancia bastante común en el universo y el sistema solar, donde se encuentra principalmente en forma de vapor o de hielo. Es esencial para la supervivencia de todas las formas conocidas de vida. ¿Qué opina usted de ésto?



\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ref_hw10}
\end{document}
```

Some error messages I get when compiling are:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \StartBabelCommands
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \StartBabelCommands

! Undefined control sequence. \AddBabelHook
```

The log file is available here:
http://share.udec.cl/server/php/files/mkuschel/compartir/hw_10.log

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: This document works with TeXLive 2016 under Linux; there is only one error message saying that `subcaption` cannot be used with `subfig`. Maybe updating your TeX distribution helps ...

Comment: unrelated to your error but don't load both enumerate and enumitem package (they both try to redefine the `enumerate` environment)

Comment: You have incongruences on your TeX systems: it seems you have updated `spanish.ldf` (2016/03/03 v5.0p) but not the core `babel` (2008/07/08 v3.8m), which is currently 2016/04/23 3.9r. Do a thorough update to your MiKTeX.

Comment: I solved the problem using the "Package Manager" and then downloaded the respective babel package. Thanks for all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it is solved by updating the packages.